# How to restrict access to a particular file in web application deployed in Tomcat?

Tags: security, tomcat

I have a simple web application deployed in Tomcat. It has a data file as part of the webapp which the app needs to access dynamically using HTTP GET. However I don't want the users to read this file from their browser. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the file in the META-INF or WEB-INF directories. The application will still be able to access it but direct requests from the client will be blocked.